# macOS Mojave version 10.14.1 bash-3.2 expr: syntax error

Tags: bash, macos, shell, expr

I meet such error:

```
expr: syntax error
```

and my script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo `expr index "sarasara"  a`
```

how to fix it.

Comment: As an aside, that's a [useless `echo`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo), too.

Answer (score 2):

`$ man expr` gives this at the end:

> According to the POSIX standard, the use of string arguments `length`,
>   `substr`, `index`, or `match` produces undefined results. In this version of
>   `expr`, these arguments are treated just as their respective string values.

In other words, macOS' `expr` does not support `index`.

Comment: Using `expr` in Bash is borderline crazy anyway. What are you actually trying to accomplish? `var=${other%%a*}` will produce a substring of `other` whose length indicates how far into `$other` the first `a` was found.

Comment: To somewhat expand on my earlier comment, `expr` made sense in the olden days when the shell lacked a number of built-in features for string matching and arithmetic; but modern shells have those features, so `expr` should by and large be forgotten. It has a limited role in strictly POSIX shell scripts, but Bash has built-in features which cover and surpass all the capabilities of `expr`.

Answer (score 0):

try this, use shell function to simulate "expr index string  substring" :

```
index() {
   str="$1"
   substr="$2"
   var=${str%%$substr*}
   echo "(${#var} + 1 ) % (${#str} + 1)" |bc 
}
```

Comment: You don't need `bc` for simple integer arithmetic. `echo $(( (${#var} + 1) % (${#str}} + 1) ))`